# backbone marionette cancel all events on itemview - at once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a table - compositeView, with rows - itemView.
Each row has many events - click, change and more.

In certain state, I would like to 'lock' the table. disable buttons and cancel events.

Is there a nice way to cancel all events on itemview - at once?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're talking about the jQuery events created with Backbone's `events` hash. You can remove them by calling `undelegateEvents` on `Backbone.view`.

Comment: It's not working for me. Should it work for `Marionette.ItemView`?

Comment: That will prevent future events but wont 'cancel' current events

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a variable in the intialize function of the view to something along the lines of this.canWeDoEvents = true.  Then inside of each event function do a check on

```
someClickEvent: function(){

  if(this.canWeDoEvents===true)
  {
 //doevent
  }
}
```